# How can I create a view with no duplication in python?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a table which looks like this ( Table 1) :

I don't want blank rows on campaign names. I want this view instead (Table 2)

How can I do this in python using pandas?

Original Table
Concatenated 2 dataframes:

df1= campaign name, oppId, closedate

df2= campaign name,Lead Id, Lead Status

| campaign name | oppId | close date | Lead Id | Lead Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1/23/2021 |  |  |
| a | 2 | 1/24/2021 |  |  |
| a | 3 | 1/25/2021 |  |  |
| a |  |  | 4 | Qualified |
| a |  |  | 5 | pursuing |
| a |  |  | 6 | Unqualified |

How I want it to look

| campaign name | oppId | close date | Lead Id | Lead Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 1/23/2021 | 4 | Qualified |
| a | 2 | 1/24/2021 | 5 | pursuing |
| a | 3 | 1/25/2021 | 6 | Unqualified |

Comment: Instead of posting pictures of your data, copy the actual data and paste it into a table here so we can copy/paste it.

Comment: Also, please explain the logic you intend to use to go from one to the other, and show what you have done to implement it.

Comment: Just added more description @MadPhysicist

Comment: Are the campaign names really all the same, or are they supposed to be something like (a, b, c, a, b, c)?

Comment: @BilltheLizard For this example,all camapigns are same

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this given the example data is to split the dataframe by columns, drop blank rows from each resulting dataframe, then concatenate them back together.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'campaign name': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
                   'oppId': [1, 2, 3, np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   'close date': ['1/23/2021', '1/24/2021', '1/25/2021', '', '', ''],
                   'Lead Id': [np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN, 4, 5, 6],
                   'Lead Status': ['', '', '', 'Qualified', 'pursuing', 'Unqualified']})
print(df)

df1 = df[['campaign name', 'oppId', 'close date']]
df1 = df1.dropna()
print(df1)

df2 = df[['Lead Id', 'Lead Status']]
df2 = df2.dropna().reset_index()
print(df2)

df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(df3)
```

Note that you do have to reset the index on the second dataframe for the concatenation to result in only three rows. The final result is

```
  campaign name  oppId close date  index  Lead Id  Lead Status
0             a    1.0  1/23/2021      3      4.0    Qualified
1             a    2.0  1/24/2021      4      5.0     pursuing
2             a    3.0  1/25/2021      5      6.0  Unqualified
```